# Parallel image segmentation

Tags: python, object-oriented, image, opencv, multiprocessing

Follow up question [Image processing using Python OOP library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201672/image-processing-using-python-oop-library)

I want to use multiprocessing to analyze several images in parallel:

```
class SegmentationType(object):
    DISPLAY_NAME = "invalid"

    def __init__(self, filename, path):
        self.filename = filename
        self.path = path
        self.input_data = None
        self.output_data = None


    def read_image(self):
        self.input_data =  cv2.imread(self.path + self.filename)[1]

    def write_image(self):
        cv2.imwrite(self.path + self.filename.split('.')[0] + '_' + self.DISPLAY_NAME + '.png', self.output_data)

    def process(self):
        # override in derived classes to perform an actual segmentation
        pass

    def start_pipeline(self):
        self.read_image()
        self.process()
        self.write_image()

class HSV_Segmenter(SegmentationType):
    DISPLAY_NAME = 'HSV'

    def process(self):
        source = rgb_to_hsv(self.input_data)
        self.output_data = treshold_otsu(source)


class LabSegmenter(SegmentationType):
    DISPLAY_NAME = 'LAB'

    def process(self):
        source = rgb_to_lab(self.input_data)
        self.output_data = global_threshold(source)


segmenter_class = {
'hsv': HSV_Segmentation,
'lab': LAB_Segmenter
}.get(procedure)

if not segmenter_class:
    raise ArgumentError("Invalid segmentation method '{}'".format(procedure))

for img in images:
    os.chdir(img_dir)
    processor =  = segmenter_class(img, img_dir, procedure)
    processor.start_pipeline()
```

What I tried so far:

```
image_lst = os.listdir(my_image_path)

# We split the list into sublist with 5 elements because of 512 GB RAM limitation
if len(image_lst) > 4:
    nr_of_sublists = (int(len(image_lst)/2.5))
    image_sub_lst  =(np.array_split(image_lst, nr_of_sublists))
else:
    image_sub_lst = [image_lst]

# We do the analysis for each sublist
for sub_lst in image_sub_lst:
    print (sub_lst)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    
    # Call the processor 
    processor =  = segmenter_class(img, img_dir, procedure)
    processor.start_pipeline()
    # How to call map???
    pool.map(?, sub_lst)
    pool.terminate()
```

Comment: Hello, I saw you used `opencv` tag and image processing in your previous post's  title, these could be useful in this post too to increment odds of receiving  detailed answers.

Comment: _What I tried so far_ - to be clear: from what you've tried so far, is the output correct?

Comment: Also, is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Hi snowflake. Unfortunately your question is currently off-topic. Questions must [include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226). Once you have fixed the issues with your post we'll be happy to review your code.

Answer (score 2):

### A warning on version

Many of the following suggestions assume that you are using Python 3.

### Bare inheritance

```
class SegmentationType(object):
```

can be

```
class SegmentationType:
```

### Abstract statics

```
DISPLAY_NAME = "invalid"
```

should not really assign a value. Instead,

```
DISPLAY_NAME: str
```

### Unpacking `imread`

[The documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) is deeply unhelpful: it says that `imread` returns "retval". Given your usage it's obvious that reality is more complicated, because you're indexing into it. Try to unpack instead:

```
_, self.input_data = cv2.imread(self.path + self.filename)
```

### Abstract methods

`process` should `raise NotImplementedError` in the base.

### Factory

You have a factory dictionary that should be turned into a method, something like

```
def get_segmenter(name: str) -> Type[SegmentationType]:
    return {
        t.DISPLAY_NAME: t
        for t in (HSVSegmenter, LABSegmenter)
    }[name]
```

### Outer parentheses

Neither of these:

```
nr_of_sublists = (int(len(image_lst)/2.5))
image_sub_lst  =(np.array_split(image_lst, nr_of_sublists))
```

needs outer parentheses.

### Syntax

Surely this is a typo? This will not run:

```
processor =  = segmenter_class(img, img_dir, procedure)
```

nor will this:

```
pool.map(?, sub_lst)
```

Comment: Thank you very  much for your suggestions and improvements.  For the last two lines, I don't know how to call the segmenter_class in a multiprocessing way.

Comment: That part of the question is off-topic. CodeReview only covers code that is complete and working.

Comment: Ok I will ask at SO